# Why there are many "NaN" in the index after importing a MultiIndex Dataframe from an Excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file looks like below in Excel:

```
            2016-1-1    2016-1-2    2016-1-3    2016-1-4
300100  am    1           3            5           1
        pm    3           2            4           5
300200  am    2           5            2           6
        pm    5           1            3           7
300300  am    1           6            3           2
        pm    3           7            2           3
300400  am    3           1            1           3
        pm    2           5            5           2
300500  am    1           6            6           1
        pm    5           7            7           5
```

But after I imported it by pd.read_excel and printed it, it was displayed like below in Python:

```
            2016-1-1    2016-1-2    2016-1-3    2016-1-4
300100  am    1           3            5           1
NaN     pm    3           2            4           5
300200  am    2           5            2           6
NaN     pm    5           1            3           7
300300  am    1           6            3           2
NaN     pm    3           7            2           3
300400  am    3           1            1           3
NaN     pm    2           5            5           2
300500  am    1           6            6           1
NaN     pm    5           7            7           5
```

How can I solve this to make the Dataframe look like the format in Excel, without so many "NaN"? Thanks!

Comment: try expanding the width of the columns with the NaN and tell me if anything changes

Comment: If that doesn't change anything then it's most likely because the cell is being parsed as a number format and when it sees nothing it interprets it as null.. so instead parse as a text/string and if you have to insert ""  from code

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time when Excel looks like what you have in your example, it does actually have blanks where those spaces are.  But, the cells are merged, so it looks pretty.  When you import it into pandas, it reads them as empty or NaN.

To fix it, forward fill the empty cells, then set as the index.

```
df.ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the Excel files or knowledge of the versions it's impossible to be sure, but it just looks like you have a column of numbers (the first column) with every other row blank. Pandas expects uniformly filled columns, so while in Excel you have a sort of "structure" of the information for both AM and PM for each first-column number (id?), Pandas just sees two rows, one with an invalid first column. Depending on how you actually want to access this data, an easy fix would be to replace every NaN with the number directly above it, so each row contains either the AM or PM information for the "id". Another fix would be to change your column structure to have 2016-1-1-am and 2016-1-1-pm fields.

Comment: I tried replacing a few NaN with the number directly above it in Excel before importing the file, and it did work. But how to do that with pandas in a fast way? I know I can use "replace" if they are values in columns, but I don't know how to deal with index. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the fillna method:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```